# Using a dictionary to store & read values to change cell color and call macro

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have a form on a sheet (Sheet2), I would like for the values entered in the D column cells to be compared to a list of values on a different sheet (Sheet5, column C). If the value entered in the D column of Sheet2 equals any of the values in Sheet5 column C, I want the F column cell in the same row of Sheet2 to turn red. If D7 = a value in column C of Sheet5, I'd like F7 to turn red. Ultimately I want this to check if any of the values in the D column are associated with macros I have created for certain values but I am trying to avoid hard coding anything.

I have started doing this by setting up a dictionary in my VBA code but I've never used dictionaries before and the code I have so far isn't working as I'd like. With this code, the cells in the F column of Sheet2 do not turn red.

```
Option Explicit
Sub estArrays()

Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


' Read to dictionary
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 17
    dict.Add Sheet5.Range("C" & i).Value, 1
Next i

' Read column d
For i = 7 To 446
    If dict.Exists(Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value) Then
        ' Set to Red
        Sheet2.Range("F" & i).Interior.Color = 3
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

FYI: values are derived from a "MID" formula in column D on Sheet2 so, the values entered in column D are not manually entered. Thanks in advance for any answers/feedback/suggestions.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a conditional format instead?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I am having trouble figuring out the Conditional Formatting since I am comparing two ranges from different sheets and want a range that isn't being compared to change cell color. If you have any other suggestions on how to go about that or any other external resources, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Figure out what formula you would use in a separate column; make that formula return TRUE for red, FALSE for anything else; once you have that formula, take it and make it your conditional formatting formula. Likely a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`, or a `VLOOKUP`.